# Is there a way to authorize myself with OAuth 2.0 using pure Java?

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

So I am creating a Java application with Apache HTTP requests that only I plan on using (which means I know my username and password for the server that I want to authenticate with). All the examples online that I have been able to find have involved a web application where the user was sent to the site they want to authenticate with (such as Facebook or Stack Exchange). However, I want to be able to authenticate solely through Java. So is there a way in which I can authenticate solely with Java?

Comment: That seems odd that they don't have any way to do it. That is disappointing. :/

Comment: They don't want you to collect usernames and passwords. So there is no reason to have that. Just get an accesstoken and store that

Comment: What would an accesstoken do for me? Sorry but I am really new to the whole OAuth thing and the tutorials are over my head.

Comment: OAuth works **because** it requires a user to login via the service's hosted website - thus allowing the service provider to be responsible for authenticating the user. This is (usually) a one-time thing though, because after you login via the authentication portal the service provider will give out a token, which can be then used in place of web based authentication. Different services have different OAuth workflows, and I know of a couple that allow you to get tokens (they may be limited in ability) by passing credentials to an endpoint. What API  are you trying to work with?

Comment: Just saw facebook tag - [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks) has links to java sdks that can walk you through authentication/and api use.

Answer (score 1):

[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) is one of the authorization flows defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). If your authorization server supports the flow, you can ask the authorization server to issue an access token by presenting your `username` and `password`.

In the flow, an authorization page is not displayed and redirection does not occur.

Comment: Hmm... I am trying to implement this for the Stack Exchange API (I tagged it as facebook because they use very similar APIs). Do you know if they allow this flow? I am trying  to get it setup but am having some trouble.

Comment: I am using the following tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-oauthjavapt1/   and everything goes through but when I submit the request for my access token I get a response code of "Found 302". This leads me to believe that I am querying the wrong URL for my request. I am using https://stackexchange.com/oauth for the authentication server which I believe is correct though.

Comment: "RFC 6749, 4.3." says "The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not viable." So, in normal cases, Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant is not supported. The primary purpose of OAuth is to allow a third-party application to access end-user data WITHOUT passing ID and password to the application. From a viewpoint of OAuth, what you are trying to do is not recommended. You should not expect famous OAuth servers support Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant.